# html form option value of mysql database only stores first word

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, echo

I was able to populate a dropdown question html form with results from my database.  However, the item I am choosing is a name, and although both the first and last name show up in the menu option, when it is submitted, only the first name is showing up.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM communications";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='client1'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value=".$row['name'].">";
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "</option>";} 
echo "</select>";?>
<input type="submit" name= "submit2" value="Show">
<input type="hidden" name= "submit3" value="Submit">
</form> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit3'])) 
{ echo $_POST['client1'];   }
```

client1 is only echoing out the first name, not the second.  Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the given string in select option value as,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        echo "<option value='".$name."'>";
                            ^         ^
```

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/871050). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Would you please consider NOT using shortened URLs in your answers? I've unshorted those same URLs a number of times now and it's getting a bit old...